# apply function to textreuse corpus

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining, corpus

I have a data frame as follows:

```
df<-data.frame(revtext=c('the dog that chased the cat', 'the dog which chased the cat', 'World Cup Hair 2014 very funny.i can change', 'BowBow', 'this is'), rid=c('r01','r02','r03','r04','r05'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

                             revtext        rid
             the dog that chased the cat    r01
             the dog which chased the cat   r02
World Cup Hair 2014 very funny.i can change r03
             Bow Bow                        r04
             this is                        r05
```

I'm using the package `textreuse` to convert `df` to a `corpus` doing:

```
#install.packages(textreuse)
library(textreuse)
d<-df$revtext
names(d)<-df$rid
corpus <- TextReuseCorpus(text = d,
                      tokenizer = tokenize_character, k=3,
                      progress = FALSE,
                      keep_tokens = TRUE)
```

where `tokenize_character` is a function I programmed as:

```
 tokenize_character <- function(document, k) {
                       shingles<-c()
                 for( i in 1:( nchar(document) - k + 1 ) ) {
                         shingles[i] <- substr(document,start=i,stop= (i+k-1))
                     }
return( unique(shingles) )  
}
```

However, I'm prompted with some warnings: `Skipping document with ID 'r04' because it has too few words to create at least two n-grams with n = 3.`. But note that my tokenizer works on a character level. The text of `r04` is long enough. In fact, if we run `tokenize_character('BowBow',3)` we get: `"Bow" "owB" "wBo"` as desired.

Note also that for `r01`, `TextReuseCorpus` is working as it is supposed, returning: `` tokens(corpus)$`r01= "the" "he " "e d" " do" "dog" "og " "g t" " th" "tha" "hat" "at " "t c" " ch" "cha" "has" "ase" "sed" "ed " "d t" "e c" " ca" "cat" ``

Any suggestions? I don't know what I'm missing here.

Comment: You have already put a lot of information here.  But I don't quite understand the objective of your work.  If you were doing text mining, why do you expect to have some segments, e.g. 'ca', 'ed'?

Comment: I want to compute similarity among the texts. Even if this doesn’t make sense, the function shouldn’t behave as that. I mean, the question is not asking whether text mining is appropriate.

Comment: OK, make sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the details section of `textreuse::TextReuseCorpus` [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/textreuse/index.html):

> If skip_short = TRUE, this function will skip very short or empty
>   documents. A very short document is one where there are two few words
>   to create at least two n-grams. For example, if five-grams are
>   desired, then a document must be at least six words long.  If no value of n is 
>   provided, then the function assumes a value of n = 3.

From this, we know documents having < 4 words will be skipped as short documents (as n=3 in your example), which is what we see for `r04` & `r05` that have 1 & 2 words, respectively. 
To not skip these documents, you can use `skip_short = F` which will return the output as intended:

```
corpus <- TextReuseCorpus(text = d, tokenizer = tokenize_character, k=3,
                      skip_short = F, progress = FALSE, keep_tokens = TRUE)
tokens(corpus)$r04
[1] "Bow" "owB" "wBo"
```